# Windows 11 with remote desktop gesture issue

Tags: windows, gesture, remote-desktop

I work on a laptop with touchpad with windows 11 pro by connecting to a computer with standard keyboard + mouse through windows remote desktop.

When I use gesture (i.e swipping 3 finger up) on my laptop (while being in fullscreen on remote desktop), it triggers the gesture on my laptop while I'd expect it to trigger on my remote computer.

Is there something I can do about this ?